# Continuous Map on Compact Oriented Manifold of Higher Degree

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Let $M$ be a compact oriented manifold of dimension $\ge 3$.
Is there any known obstructions of $M$ for it to admit a continuous self-map of degree $>1$?

Note: the case when $\dim(M) = 2$ is known (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234889/the-biggest-degree-of-a-map-between-fixed-surfaces?rq=1)).

Remark: In (the top answer of) the post above, it was explained that if $M$ has positive simplicial volume (denoted as $||M||$), then it does not admit a self-map of degree $>1$. However, if $M$ is simply-connected, we have $||M|| = 0$. So 2 follow-up questions are:

1. Let $M$ be a **simply-connected** compact oriented manifold of dimension $\ge 3$.
   Is there any known obstructions of $M$ for it to admit a continuous self-map of degree $>1$?
2. Original question, replace "obstruction" with "obstruction other than simplicial-volume".

Answer (score 2):

This was studied quite a bit in the 3-dimensional case. The main obstruction is positive simplicial volume, e.g. hyperbolic manifolds do not admit such maps. For details see

*Sun, Hongbin; Wang, Shicheng; Wu, Jianchun; Zheng, Hao*, [**Self-mapping degrees of 3-manifolds**](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1801), Osaka J. Math. 49, No. 1, 247-269 (2012). [ZBL1241.55002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1241.55002).

Comment: Thanks for the paper! Right, what you said about positive simplicial volume applies to manifolds of any dimension. Are there any obstructions other than positive simplicial volume?

Comment: @abracadabra12345 Of course. Just keep reading the paper.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will do.